# PhysX3: addTorque() and addForce() have no effect on a PxRigidDynamic

Tags: physx

I have updated my project from PhysX2 to PhysX3 and after clearing most of the problems with different mathematical data types and other issues, I still have one issue remaining.

The problem is now that whenever I use addTorque() function, it has no effect on a rigid body. addForce() and it's variations induce lateral movement but if applied asymmetrically, they don't induce torque also. I don't think the body is constraint in any way because if I use setAngularVelocity(), the body rotates as it should at the set speed.

What could possibly be wrong in such a situation and what else can I try to pinpoint the problem?

If it matters, my timestep is 1.0f/60.0f

Comment: edit: I tried angular damping 0.0f, 0.05f (default) and a few higher values.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the problem was setting the intertia tensor to zero (leftover from old version of the project). Once I used PxRigidBodyExt::updateMassAndInertia() on the body, torque began to function properly.